# Generate data communication flow graph (C program, profiling)

Tags: c, memory, profiling, code-analysis, callstack

I want to be able to generate a communication/call graph which contains information regarding the amount of data passed between functions.

so for example :

**function1() -----> [Object *ptr] ----> function2()**

which means function 1 passes a pointer to an object to function 2 (and vice versa). BUT, if *ptr points to an object that is 1MB (lets say). then the graph should look like :

**function1() ----> [Object *ptr::1MB] -----> function2()**

which will give us a rough understanding of how (and what type/size/format of data) is passed .something that looks like :

1. http://cms.uni-kassel.de/unicms/uploads/pics/TASK_GRAPH_01.JPG
2. http://www.prace-ri.eu/IMG/png/gprof.png

I can obtain a graph like (2) by using gprof profiling and the gprof2dot script, but the output of this only shows cpu usage %. I want to see the amount of data passed between them as well.

Is there a tool (either opensource/commercial) that can provide this, or do you know of a combination of tools that can be used to obtain this information ?

(I was thinking combining the analysis by Valgrind + gprof, but was wondering if there was a more direct approach..

Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is that with pointers (in C) you do not know the size of what they are pointing to.  an 'int *' may be an array of 0, 1, 5, 100, or 1500000.  And if it's a void *, all bets are off.  I don't know of any programmatic way of doing this.

Comment: I would use graphviz for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a call graph that handles function pointers.

Using that, you need to identify the data flows, e.g., the values passed between elements of the call graph.   For scalar values, the size of the scalar is pretty obvious.   For pointer values, the *pointer* size may be relatively obvious, but the amount of data flowing to the called function is a matter of what pointers are dereferenced, and how much data is processed by the dereference.   For that, if you have a "pointer to T" and the pointer is deferenced to fetch a "whole value", the size you need is the sizeof(T).   If T is a compound type, an access of "p->q" has size T.q.   So you need all the type information from the program, if you want to collect this data statically.

For this, you need a C parser, name and type resolution, control and dataflow analysis.  You can't do this with "just a C parser".

You can get this with GCC or Clang or with tools like our DMS.  My belief is that getting this information from GCC isn't easy; it is designed to be compiler, not an analysis tool.  Clang sounds like it is easier to use (I have no personal experience); DMS was designed for this kind of task but people's opinion may vary.

You also need the ability to construct the call graphs and then rewalk the dataflows of each module.  I think this would be hard with GCC; it wants to compile just one compilation unit at a time.  Clang I think can process multiple compilation units at once.  DMS can, and we've built call graphs with points-to analysis for single load images of 26 million lines.

No matter which you choose, it is a pretty fair exercise to set up the tools to extract what you want.  [What would you do with the answer?]

Comment: The data obtained will be used to merge with another call-graph to come up with a functional communication data flow. A way to build up an application model, which includes resource usage of an application (e.g. memory, cpu, communication channels - in a MPSoC). probably think about mapping different functions on to different Cores in a Network on chip and because of this we need to know the data volume.

Comment: You'd probably like my paper on "Mechanically translating a legacy application into a Network Application" which basically does just that.  See page 12 in NetCentric proceedings: netcentriccomputing.org/2001/NCC2001.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this ! any idea if the 'DMS software reengineering toolkit' mentioned in this paper is available for free use (for academic research purposes ?)

Comment: It isn't free to academics, but there's an enormous discount.  Contact the company.